# Running a three node riak cluster using a homebrew installation

Tags: macos, homebrew, riak

I installed Riak on my Mac via homebrew, and would like to set up a local three node cluster.

The [basho fast track tutorial](http://wiki.basho.com/Building-a-Development-Environment.html) is however based on a source build, and as far as I know, those instructions won't apply to my homebrew install (e.g. `make devrel` will generate 3 nodes, but my install doesn't contain the  makefile).

I tried making 3 copies of `/usr/local/Cellar/riak`, named `dev1`, `dev2` and `dev3`. Then I adjusted the `http`, `handoff_port` and `pb_port` settings in `devN/1.1.1x86_64/libexec/etc/app.config` as well as the `-name` setting in  `devN/1.1.1x86_64/libexec/etc/vm.args` (I used 81XX for the ports used by node dev1, 82XX for those used by node dev2, etc. For the `-name`setting I used `riak1@127.0.0.1`, `riak2@127.0.0.1`, etc).

Node dev1 can successfully be started using `./dev1/1.1.1x86_64/bin/riak start`. But upon starting node dev2 using `./dev2/1.1.1x86_64/bin/riak start`, riak complains that the node is already running.

How do I get riak to recognize the three installations as separate nodes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is the `RUNNER_SCRIPT_DIR` variable in the `./devN/1.1.1x86_64/bin/riak` scripts - It's set to `/usr/local/Cellar/riak/1.1.1x86_64/libexec/bin` in the original homebrew version you copied.

This is used later in the script in the `ping_node` function (and actually, everything else). The `-name` and `-setcookie` and all the other settings are being pulled out of the `vm.args` in `/usr/local/Cellar/riak/1.1.1x86_64/libexec/etc` directory instead of the copies you made.

Change that in each of your copies of the `riak` script and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks, Brian. I wrote a little script to set up the nodes from a homebrew riak installation:  http://ottopoellath.github.com/blog/2012/04/08/running-a-three-node-riak-cluster-using-a-homebrew-installation/

Comment: In newer version of riak `RUNNER_SCRIPT_DIR` is now set in `libexec/lib/env.sh`